# Excel macro that returns all values for lookup for a range

Tags: vba, excel

I know that heading may seem Ultra confusing but it's the best way I could do.

To give further explaination I have a single work book and two sheets:

- Sheet A has people's names in row 1 (A1, B1, C1, etc). The number of names changes, sometimes more sometimes less.
- Sheet B has the list of people's names in Column A and a value in Column B. For example:

  ```
  A       B
  John    22
  John    13
  Sam     90
  ```

What I need is a macro that looks at the value in the first row in each column in Sheet A and returns pastes all the matching values from the list in Sheet B to the second row in Sheet A.

It would look something like:

- Sheet A:

  ```
  A        B
  John     Sam
  22       90
  13
  ```

I haven't had the time to test anything up but I was thinking that I might be able to paste a formula in B1:B[X] that looks up the number of times the names occurs in the list and finds its starting position and use that to copy and paste the corresponding range from column B.

I'm not a macro pro but that's the direction my mind is going right now. If anyone could make sense of that dry explanation and could help that would be amazing!

Comment: I recommend you use Excel Tables and Excel formulae using Index/Match. Google Excel Tables and Index:/Match.  Here are a couple of links to get you started.  [23 Things to Know about Excel Tables](https://exceljet.net/things-to-know-about-excel-tables) and [Excel Formula Basic Index Match](https://exceljet.net/formula/basic-index-match-exact).  I have no affilation with any of these sites. I've gotten great help from Stack Overflow over the years, and I'm trying to pay it forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think easiest way is to use collection / dictionary. I am assuming that all your names in sheet A is unique.

```
Option Explicit

Sub RetrieveData()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws_A As Worksheet
Dim ws_B As Worksheet

Dim HeaderRow As Long
Dim HeaderLastColumn As Long
Dim TableColStart As Long
Dim NameList As Object
Dim i As Long

Dim ws_B_lastrow As Long
Dim NextEntryline As Long
Dim NameCol As Long

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set ws_A = wb.Worksheets("Sheet A")
Set ws_B = wb.Worksheets("Sheet B")
Set NameList = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

With ws_A
    HeaderRow = 1  'set the header row in sheet A
    TableColStart = 1 'Set start col in sheet A
    HeaderLastColumn = .Cells(HeaderRow, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column  'Get number of NAMEs you have

    For i = TableColStart To HeaderLastColumn
        If Not NameList.Exists(UCase(.Cells(HeaderRow, i).Value)) Then  'check if the name exists in the dictionary
             NameList.Add UCase(.Cells(HeaderRow, i).Value), i 'if does not exist record name as KEY and Column number as value in dictionary
        End If
    next i

End With




With ws_B
    ws_B_lastrow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row  ' Get number of DATA you have in sheet B
    For i = 1 To ws_B_lastrow   'for each data
        NameCol = NameList(UCase(.Cells(i, 1).Value))  'get the column where the name is in Sheet A from the dictionaary
        If NameCol <> 0 Then  'if 0 means the name doesnt exists
            NextEntryline = ws_A.Cells(Rows.Count, NameCol).End(xlUp).Row + 1 'get the next entry line of the particular name in sheet A
            ws_A.Cells(NextEntryline, NameCol).Value = .Cells(i, 2) 'insert the data
        End If

    Next i
End With


End Sub
```

Comment: Don't ever use `GoTo` unless it is immediately  behind `On Error`, using `GoTo` is a very bad practice and  can easily be avoided by negating the `If` statement here: `If NameCol <> 0 Then … NextEntryline … End If`.

Comment: edited as per Peh Advice,  to advocate good Coding Practice !!

Answer (score 0):

The way I understand: Something like a timecard report generator, or an arbitrary list of names and values in Sheet2, and you want to transpose and consolidate Sheet2 onto Sheet1 in a Pivot Table-like consolidation (sure you can't just use a Pivot?).

Pure VBA-wise I did something like this a few years ago (my use case being that above-mentioned timecard report):

1. Sort Sheet2 by your name column.
2. Calculate the last row using `lastrow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row`.
3. Also initialize a row rounter (RCTR) and column counter (CCTR) which will iterate or reset as your output table is written.
4. Begin a for-next through this entire, sorted raw list known as Sheet2 (`For n = 1 To lastrow ... Next n`).
5. For each row, compare `Range("A" & n)` with `Range("A" & n-1)` to determine when a new name occurs (*you'll override this test and just assume a new name for Row 1*).
6. If a new name occurs per step 4, reset RCTR to 2 and iterate CCTR by 1, then copy that new name into `Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1,CCTR)` (column is the current column counter, row is 1).
7. Copy over the the numeric values into `Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(RCTR,CCTR)`, then iterate RCTR.
8. Loop to Step 5.

Since the worksheet is sorted, we only care when the name column in Sheet2 changes, and therefore can pretty much ignore how many times it occurs in a given dataset.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to loop through all data in Sheet B, match them with the first row in Sheet A and if it matched write the value into the next free row in the matched column.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub SortDataIntoSheetA()
    Dim wsSrc As Worksheet
    Set wsSrc = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet B") 'define source worksheet

    Dim wsDest As Worksheet
    Set wsDest = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet A") 'define destination worksheet

    Dim LastSrcRow As Long
    LastSrcRow = wsSrc.Cells(wsSrc.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'find last used row in source

    Dim DestCol As Long, LastDestRow As Long

    Dim iRow As Long
    For iRow = 1 To LastSrcRow 'loop throug all rows in source
        DestCol = 0 'initialize
        On Error Resume Next 'if next row throws error hide it
        DestCol = WorksheetFunction.Match(wsSrc.Cells(iRow, "A").Value, wsDest.Rows(1), 0) 'find correct column
        On Error GoTo 0 're-enable error reporting!!

        'if nothing matched DestCol will still be 0

        If DestCol > 0 Then
            LastDestRow = wsDest.Cells(wsDest.Rows.Count, DestCol).End(xlUp).Row 'find last used row in destination column
            wsDest.Cells(LastDestRow + 1, DestCol).Value = wsSrc.Cells(iRow, "B").Value 'write value
        End If
    Next iRow
End Sub
```